# Kendo Masked Textbox max and min length property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, data-masking

We have couple of masked textboxes Phone,Mobile) with proper masking but can't able to set the length validation. display:none is set automatically which bared validation message to be display over UI. Please help.

Comment: You'll need to show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use data annotations in your model to set length for your input. If it is digits use something like:

```
[StringLength(int.MaxValue, MinimumLength = 7)]
```

If it is string use something like:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?:.*[a-z]){7,}$", ErrorMessage = "String length must be greater than or equal 7 characters.")]
```

Comment: The OP is looking for a front end approach, this is back end.